# C# with WPF - Keyboard not binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to enable, disable and re-enable certain keyboard strokes in my WPF program based on certain conditions. I have the binding currently like this:

```
//MainWindow.xaml
...
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding UpCommand}" Key="Up"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding DownCommand}" Key="Down"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding LeftCommand}" Key="Left"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding RightCommand}" Key="Right"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
...
```

And then in the ViewModel:

```
//MLViewModel.cs
class MLViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public DelegateCommand UpCommand { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand DownCommand { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand LeftCommand { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand RightCommand { get; private set; }

    public MLViewModel(MLModel model)
    {
    ...
        Lvl1Command = new DelegateCommand(param => { SetUpGame(MLModel.Level.Easy); });
        Lvl2Command = new DelegateCommand(param => { SetUpGame(MLModel.Level.Medium); });
        Lvl3Command = new DelegateCommand(param => { SetUpGame(MLModel.Level.Hard); });

        UpCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => { _model.MoveUp(); RefreshTable(); });
        DownCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => { _model.MoveDown(); RefreshTable();});
        LeftCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => { _model.MoveLeft(); RefreshTable(); });
        RightCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => { _model.MoveRight(); RefreshTable(); });    
     }

     private void SetUpGame(MLModel.Level level)
     {
     // setting up the field etc.
     }

    private void Model_GameOver(object sender, MLEventArgs e)
    {
    // handling the event of the game being over
    }
}
```

Now, this works as supposed, except that the key binding is enabled all the time while the program is running. The gamefield doesn't disappear after a game is finished, but I don't want the user to be able to move (~use the keys) until she/he starts a new game via `SetUpGame()`. And that's why I'd like to move the `[Up-Down-Left-Right]Command` binding to `SetUpGame()` instead of the constructor (and unbind it in `Model_Gameover`). However, if I do move the instantiation of the new DelegateCommands to `SetUpGame()`, the key binding doesn't happen and I'm unable to play. `Lvl[1-2-3]Command` works as expected, but the keyboard binding doesn't (it does work, however, when it's in the constructor).

How can I make sure the key binding is enabled after `SetUpGame` until a game is finished, but is disabled after `Model_GameOver` until `SetUpGame` is run again? Why is placing the `new DelegateCommand`s to `SetUpGame()` not working? Thank you!

**ADDITION**

I have IPropertyChanged implemented as follows:

```
namespace SavageMaci.ViewModel
{
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected ViewModelBase() { }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, even if I'm trying

```
DownCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => { _model.MoveDown(); RefreshTable(); OnPropertyChanged(); });
```

it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your commands are still bound properties, just with a special type `ICommand`. That means that it works *the same as any other binding*. If you want elements to pick up a change to a bound property they need to raise `PropertyChanged`. Because your commands are using auto-properties, that event isn't raised.

The reason you don't *normally* have to do this is property assignments in a constructor happen before the bindings evaluate.

As for "removing" the bindings; you could set them to null (and raise `PropertyChanged` as appropriate) but a better solution would be to use a `DelegateCommand` (or a custom command object) that supports `CanExecute/CanExecuteChanged` and use that to "disable" the commands when the program isn't in a valid state.

Comment: Sorry, I was not accurate describing my own problem.. The Level commands work fine, the keystroke commands don't. I've added the implementation of `IPropertyChanged` to the question, which I had already implemented.

Comment: Oh wait it does work if I explicitly add `OnPropertyChange("UpCommand")` etc.

Comment: As for the removing of the bindings, I'm trying `DownCommand.CanExecute(false);` and afterwards `OnPropertyChanged("DownCommand");`, but this doesn't disable the binding. Am I missing something?

Comment: @lte__ Yes, you are missing something. The *framework* invokes `CanExecute`. If the return value has changed the command object needs to raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event. Lucky for you, you know *exactly* when this change happens so if you invoke that event (through a `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method likely) the framework will pick it up. At that point you don't need to raise `PropertyChanged` anymore

Comment: @lte__ You may want to read into the WPF Command docs a little bit to make sure you understand exactly why/how all this works :)